# Change the "src" attribute keeping the initial size , with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

To do this I used this code

```
$("#my_img_id").attr("src", "images/img1.svg");
```

on this type of image

```
<img id='my_img_id' src='images/img2.svg' style='width:45px;height:45px;'>
```

The problem is as follows: This code works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, but on Safari (both on mac and on iphone5s, while on ipad 3 there are no problems) when i change the image src, the image does not maintain the size (45*45px) initials, but "exit" from the original image size

[image]

Comment: You should set up a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: You would likely have better overall performance and functionality if you used an image sprite and background-images/positions (and it'l probably bypass that *bug*)

Comment: If you check the source html in safari after you choose the larger image, does it still show style='width:45px;height:45px;'?

Comment: @KevinB not if the width and height change.  This isn't a traditional sprite implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reply your problem, but can not.
[See demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3Jdy/1/)

Maybe its work only for `.jpg` but not `.svg`

Anyway I hope jsFiddle can help see changes online.